# How to measure the battery consumption of my app under ios?

Tags: ios

I need to get battery consumption details for my app. Is their any tool to measure the battery consumption of my app under ios ? i mean  how to profile and see how good the metrics are ?

Comment: Do you mean how to profile and see how good the metrics are? If that's what you want then make an edit to your question

Answer (score 0):

Couple of steps you need to do, but i think it's possible, already done it before.

First enable battery monitoring:

```
UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
```

Then you need something to get battery level, so create a property that will return batteryLevel:

```
var batteryLevel: Float {
    return UIDevice.current.batteryLevel
}
```

To check device battery level add an observer for the UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChange notification:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(batteryLevelDidChange), name: .UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChange, object: nil)
func batteryLevelDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    print(batteryLevel)
}
```

This should give you the battery level

Comment: thanks ppinho ! but this is for all the app ? i want to know how much battery is consumed because of my app ...

Comment: Nop, this is to read the battery level of the phone when this code runs. What you can do, is to save the initial value, and do the math after some operation on your side.